# can't make append after jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside clientProfile.html I have a div with class name clientName. And after loading the file inside ajax success, I want to append "hi" to that div, but doesn't work.

**JS**:

```
function renderClientProfile() {

    $(".wrapper").load("./clientProfile.html");
}

success: function(data) {

   renderClientProfile();
   $(".clientName").append("hi");
}
```

Comment: can you post here the entire Ajax method, nut just the "success" callback

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$( ".wrapper" ).load( "./clientProfile.html", function() {
    $(".clientName").append("hi");
});
```